# Как реализовать вызов метода с определенным интервалом в Telegram bot?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Имеется сервис, который при помощи Spring Scheduling c определенным интервалом вытаскивает из базы данные. Можно ли реализовать отправку сообщений ботом по тому же шедулингу ? И можно ли вызывать методы бота извне ?

Comment: Что значит `извне`? Ваш бот — отдельное исполняемое приложение, или он внутри спринг-приложения? Если он внутри, что вам мешает по `Spring Scheduling` его тоже дёргать? А если снаружи, то можно напрямую, а не через враппер в виде `Spring Scheduling` дёргать `cron`.

Comment: Мой бот является частью сервиса , нужно реализовать отправку данных из БД с заданным интервалом  через Telegram bot .Интересует можно ли использовать SendMessage, к  примеру , из класса Service ,в котором реализуется вся часть логики ,отвечающая за отправку?